# Can Dropships be shot down?

Tags: half-life-2

In Half-life 2, there are Dropships and Gunships. Gunships fire bullets at you, and can be easily shot down with a rocket launcher. Dropships deploy Combine troops.

Is it possible to use a Rocket Launcher to take down a Dropship from the air?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [Combine dropships](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Combine_Dropship) are immune to all player weapons. However, the containers they carry can be destroyed with 4 direct RPG hits or sustained airboat fire (e.g. in *Root Kanal*).